# Difference Between Wordpress Orignal Theme and Child Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes, child-theming

What is the difference between Wordpress Orignal Theme and Child Theme?

Is that necessary to make a child theme after end project or there is no need.

Answer (score 1):

The most important advantage of a child theme is the fact that you can change/add to the functionality or styling of the parent theme without changing the actual parent themes' templates. The advantage are, if you have a theme that you have not coded, and you need to change some functionality and/or styling, you will not loose any customizations if you update the parent theme if your custom code is in a child theme. Child themes are the safest and most recommended way of making changes to a parent theme